# Which does "go down" mean, digest or swallow?

Tags: proverbs, idioms-in-context

Sugar really helps the medicine **go down**!

In this sentence does **"go down"** mean to *digest* or to *swallow*?

Comment: In the most delightful way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. It means *be easily swallowed*. Note that this construction uses the passive voice, whereas your second proposed meaning uses the active.